# How do I stop an adb port forward?

Tags: android, sockets, port, adb, portforwarding

One can forward a port with `adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080`. But do I need to kill the adb server to stop this forwarding?

I'm looking for a way to stop forwarding of a port in adb, after it was set up, but when the forward is no longer needed.

Comment: why you looking for this way? After unplug USB, it get reset, or create other port instead

Comment: @MaximShoustin I'm using an AVD, not a real device. Also, I would like my AVD keep running.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try `adb forward --remove tcp:8080`, or `adb forward --remove-all`.

This was added to adb in December 2012 ([see patch here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/46371/)).  The SDK update released for Android 4.3 (API 18) was the first to support it.

Comment: This also applies if you opened the port using `adb reverse` (so almost exactly as above: `adb reverse --remove tcp:8080` or `--remove-all`). You can also view the open ports using `adb reverse --list`