# Appium Error: Cannot find any free port in range 8200..8299

Tags: testing, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

I'm running about 90 tests in Appium (Android emulator on iMac) and it was all fine until suddenly I started observing this error:

```
Starting logs capture with command: /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 logcat -v threadtime
     E       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side
 error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot find any free port in range
 8200..8299}. Please set the available port number by providing the systemPort capability or
 double check the processes that are locking ports within this range and terminate these which
 are not needed anymore
```

I did a few things to fix this problem but nothing worked:

1.

```
adb kill-server    
adb reconnect
```

2. I did clean the emulator and restarted too.
3. Apart from this, I didn't find any port from 8200-8299 which is already being used in the system.
4. I did add `systemPort` capability as well but still I see the same error.

I have no idea how to fix this.

**UPDATE:**

Found some more logs and figured out that the port forwarding isn't being cleared by UIAutomator 2 (or adb) that's why I don't have issues with iOS but have issued in Android only. Here are the logs which is at the end of the appium server:

```
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy] [39m Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8200/wd/hub/session/d1f94433-2c44-4dac-a836-461ab7f41130] with no body
[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2] [39m Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy] [39m Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[debug] [35m[WD Proxy] [39m Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8201/wd/hub/session/37137b29-a9a6-4d83-b2d9-ce510f601a2d] with no body
[debug] [35m[UiAutomator2] [39m Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
```

where `127.0.0.1:8201` goes upto `127.0.0.1:8299` and deletes 100 active sessions which I don't expect.

Also, in netstat output I do see that TCP ports 127.0.0.1:8200 - 127.0.0.1:8299 (LISTEN) are open

Comment: Did you end up finding a fix for this?

Comment: Yes, by using `--session-override` command line argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this. I am trying this now.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding --session-override flag while starting the appium server did not help my case. Anything else that you added in addition to that flag ? Did you have the --session-override port with the systemPort capability as well at the same time >

Comment: I did not use systemPort capability. I just used the flag. I noticed in logs after adding the flag it did not do port forwarding so more than 100 tests were working. what issue do you face after adding the flag?

Comment: Hi,
I tried using --session-override flag but the error still exists.what else do i need to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute:

```
adb -s $UDID forward --remove-all
```

just before launching appium
and after to ensure that the ports used by the adb are free

see [How do I stop an adb port forward?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817275/how-do-i-stop-an-adb-port-forward)

Answer (score 0):

- Force quit the terminal
- Force quit the android studio
- Launch the device
- Run Appium command on terminal
- Run Appium Inspector

Answer (score 0):

```
adb -s $UDID forward --remove-all
```

Did not work for me
I tried this

```
--session-override
```

while creating a new appium session. This worked fine, although I am worried about the get_screenshot() method as it requires the daemon to initiate a separate session. Will update